# How to parse the stacked messages in a notification (Whatsapp notification)

Tags: android, android-notifications, whatsapp, android-notification-bar, accessibility

I am trying to parse the Whatsapp notifications that i receive on my device using `NotificationListenerService`.

On receiving a notification for the first time, i am able to retrieve the Text message. However, when the second message arrives, i get the message: "2 new messages". So basically here the messages in the notification are getting stacked.

Below is the code i have used:

```
public class NLService extends NotificationListenerService {

    private String TAG = this.getClass().getSimpleName();

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn) {
        Log.i(TAG,"**********  onNotificationPosted");
        String key = sbn.getKey();
sbn.getNotification().tickerText + "\n Package Name:" + sbn.getPackageName());
        Log.i(TAG,"getTAG:"+sbn.getTag());
        Log.i(TAG,"getKey:"+sbn.getKey());
        Log.i(TAG,"getGrpKey:"+sbn.getGroupKey());*/
        Bundle bundle = sbn.getNotification().extras;
        String title = bundle.getString("android.title");
        String text = bundle.getCharSequence("android.text").toString();//This gives me the actual message, the first time the notification arrives
        Log.i(TAG,"Bundle is:"+bundle);
        Log.i(TAG,"Title:"+title);
        Log.i(TAG,"Text:"+text);
        NLService.this.cancelNotification(key);
    }

    @Override
    public void onNotificationRemoved(StatusBarNotification sbn) {
        Log.i(TAG,"********** onNOtificationRemoved");
        Log.i(TAG,"ID :" + sbn.getId() + "\t" + sbn.getNotification().tickerText +"\t" + sbn.getPackageName());
    }
}
```

So my query here is, how do i parse/fetch messages from this notification? Or is there another way to fetch incoming whatsapp messages?

One approach that i can think of is marking the message as "Read", but has anyone able to mark a whatsapp message as "read" programmatically?

I have read most of the older posts on Stackoverflow and also whatsapp official site provides us a way of send a message.

Any sort of suggestions shall be really helpful.

Comment: You can't :). tried  this some times back :)

Comment: No workaround or anything?